# How to create a "keyless" HashSet and HashMap in Rust?

Tags: rust, hashmap, hashset

The implementations of [`HashMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html) and [`HashSet`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html) found in [`std::collections`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/index.html) both store the keys being hashed, and not just the hash. This is useful in most situations, but not all.

I am making sets and maps with quite large data as keys, and I have no need to actually read the keys back, i.e. I'm not using `my_map.keys()`. In my use case, the keys are just a giant waste of memory.

How do I create a map or a set that does not store the keys, taking a `&K` instead of an owned `K` at insertion?

Comment: You create it yourself. The standard library cannot help you. But there are data structures for this kind of problem.

Comment: Storing the keys is needed in order to handle hash collisions.

Comment: @interjay This is not always necessary, there are probablistic data structures.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Probabilistic data structures may return the wrong result, which is not something OP indicated would be acceptable.

Comment: @interjay That was my first thought when I saw the question. But maybe I was wrong and they just didn't realize that the actual keys are necessary for deterministic results.

Comment: A hash set without keys is just a bloom filter.

Comment: @interjay `Hasher::finnish` produce an `u64`. Shouldnt storing that `u64` be enough to have an extremely small risk of collisions?

Comment: @Anders `HashMap` doesn't store that `u64`. And even if it was stored, it would have a non-negligible chance of collisions due to the birthday paradox. And it's also prone to attacks if it stores user data. But of course you can use a `HashMap<u64, T>` and hash the key yourself if you want to take that risk. That approach will be safe if you use a cryptographically secure hash function such as SHA-256 with a `[u8; 32]` key.

Comment: @interjay This is not user controlled data so attacks are not a problem. I guess I will calculate the birthday collision probability and see if it is acceptable. If it is, I will use your approach of using the hash as a key. Thanks for the useful input, feel free to post it as an answer with the caveats included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard library `HashMap` needs to store the keys mainly for two reasons: checking for collisions and resizing.

The only remnant of the hash that is retained is the item's index in the internal array, which may not even be representative of the hash if the hash collided when inserted and the entry ended up in another index. So the key lets you check for equality once the index is computed from the hash.

For resizing, since the hash is not stored, all hashes need to be recomputed from the keys in order to reinsert all entries into the larger buffer.

If you can handle collisions yourself or can ignore some amount of collision, you can use an intermediate hash as a key. If the hash is random enough, you could also create the `HashMap` with a simple `Hasher` implementation that merely repeats the bytes it is given. How large and random your intermediate hash is will determine how often collisions will happen. If you put an entire sha256 hash as the key, you'll realistically never have collisions.

Answer (score 0):

This map takes `&SomeLargeData` instead of `SomeLargeData`

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
struct MyData {
    a: String,
    b: u64,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
struct SomeLargeData {
    b: String,
    c: String,
}

fn main() {
    let mut hashmap: HashMap<&SomeLargeData, MyData> = HashMap::new();

    let large_data = SomeLargeData {
        b: "hello".to_string(),
        c: "hi".to_string(),
    };
    let my_data = MyData {
        a: "hello_there".to_string(),
        b: 8u64,
    };

    hashmap.insert(&large_data, my_data);

    println!("{:?}", hashmap.get(&large_data));
}
```

Hope it is helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! For this to work, I can not drop `large_data` before I drop `hashmap`. That means I still need to keep all the keys in memory, taking up all that space. Only difference is that they're not inside the hashmap.